# How to generate Cassandra Token for composite partition key?

Tags: cassandra, murmurhash

My Cassandra ColumnFamily uses the Murmur3Partitioner, and has a composite partition key.
With this partitioner I was trying to create a Token, however it seems this token factory only allows Long values.
Is it possible to generate these hashes for something like "token(partition_column1, partition_column2)"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's supposed to work.  In fact, if your partition key is composite, you should be unable to create a token for only a single column.  Are you sure that you've defined the composite key properly?

```
cqlsh:testks> create table t1(k1 int, k2 text, v text, primary key((k1, k2)));
cqlsh:testks> insert into t1(k1, k2, v) values (1, 'key', 'value');
cqlsh:testks> select * from t1;

 k1 | k2  | v
----+-----+-------
  1 | key | value

(1 rows)

cqlsh:testks> select token(k1) from t1;
Bad Request: Invalid number of arguments in call to function token: 2 required but 1 provided
cqlsh:testks> select token(k2) from t1;
Bad Request: Invalid number of arguments in call to function token: 2 required but 1 provided
cqlsh:testks> select token(k1, k2) from t1;

 token(k1, k2)
---------------------
 8064425790465501062

    (1 rows)
```

Comment: That's correct, all statements above hold. However, I was looking for means to create such token from the java api, instead of performing queries, i.e. to generate the possible token ranges using org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner.

Comment: If you want to create it using Java APIs, you'll have to use the `partitioner.getToken(ByteBuffer)` API.  For details, you can start looking at the implementation of CQL `token()` function in https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/functions/TokenFct.java .

Answer (score 1):

This is the formula for calculating Hash, I found on Datastax web :

```
(((2**64 / number_of_tokens) * i) - 2**63) for i in range(number_of_tokens)
```

This hashing function creates a 64-bit hash value of the partition key

So the Hash can be in range of **-2^63** to +**2^63-1** (*2 to power 63*)

Answer (score 0):

The Algorithm to compute the token for a composite partition key : 
Primary_key((text, int)) -> therefore the partition key is a composite_partition_key (text, int).

Example : a row with composite_partition_key ('hello', 1)

Applying the algorithm :

**1- lay-out the components of the composite partition key in big-endian (16 bits) presentation :**

first_component = 'hello' ->  68 65 6c 6c 6f

sec_component = 1 -> 00 00 00 01

68 65 6c 6c 6f 00 00 00 01

**2- add two-bytes length of component before each component**

first_component = 'hello', length= 5-> ***00 05*** 68 65 6c 6c 6f

sec_component = 1, therefore length= 4 -> ***00 04*** 00 00 00 01

***00 05*** 68 65 6c 6c 6f ***00 04*** 00 01

**3- add zero-value after each component**

first_component = 'hello' -> ***00 05*** 68 65 6c 6c 6f  ***00***

sec_component = 1 -> ***00 04*** 00 00 00 01 ***00***

**4- result**

**00 05** 68 65 6c 6c 6f ***00*** **00 04** 00 00 00 01 ***00***

now pass the result as whatever binary base your murmur3 function understand (make sure it's cassandra variant).